# Is this kind of "ideal thermal photon rocket" possible?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, reflection, rocket-science

Ideal thermal photon rocket:

- You have a 1 GW radioactive heat source in your spaceship.  As a result, your whole spaceship heats up and begins emitting thermal radiation in all directions.
- You use several concentric shells of mirrors positioned around the ship to reflect all the thermal radiation in one direction.  The ship begins to accelerate in the opposite direction.  To an outside observer, the ship appears as cold as space from all non-exhaust directions.

Is this thermodynamically possible?  I'm suspicious this would be breaking the second law of thermodynamics, because it seems to costlessly go from "emitting heat in all directions" to "emitting heat in one specific direction."  If it does work, would the outermost shell of mirrors need to be very large?

Comment: I don’t see a Second Law violation; can you elaborate? Note that you’d need to cool the (imperfect) mirrors to keep *them* from heating up.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm just double checking.  It almost seems like concentrating all the diffuse heat into one super-hot direction would be moving heat from a cooler place to a hotter place?  But maybe that is OK because new heat is being generated all the time.  Cooling the mirrors may be a challenge because the only place to eject heat is the already very hot exhaust.  Is it possible?  Do you even need the mirrors, can you just circulate a refrigerant to cool the exterior of the ship and eject heat into the exhaust?